# Can I pass the ViewModel to a RecyclerView Adapter and observe a LiveData?

Tags: android, mvvm, data-binding, android-recyclerview

I'm started to implement `MVVM` and I do not know if use the `ViewModel` inside my `Adapter` is a Good Practice or an AntiPattern.

To give you an example, think about a list of colors and an Image that you will change the background. In that case, I'm observing the selected Color and binding the background color to display in the UI.

But I'm observing the colorSelected in two places:

- In the `Fragment` in order to change the background color
- In the `Adapter` to display which color is selected

So, Am I using `MVVM` properly when I passing and observing the `ViewModel` to the `Adapter`?

Comment: did you find an efficient solution to your problem?

Comment: kinda, but I'm not happy with it, I know if I added here no one will suggest a solution.
Do you have a solution?

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure now if it is good pattern, but there is one problem with this:
this way your adapter is tied to your ViewModel meaning you can't reuse it with other ViewModel on another screen. On another hand it is much easier to work without those additional callbacks from recyclerView which makes implementation easier. I guess it is "better" to use callbacks, but "easier" to pass ViewModel (I think CG should deal with it without a problem)

Comment: when you said "I'm not sure now" is because you are looking for a better answer?

Comment: Thanks by the way

Comment: @AndroidStorm I was looking for answer too, but the main reason is one programmer will say it is better to make code more elastic with more work and another one will say "why do I need to make more elastic code when it requires much more work". I think it depends on the project :)

Comment: I just found an article that says something like a Recyclerview is a view that does not have any relation with your project. So it should not have a reference to your models. But still looking for the right answer.

Comment: @AndroidStorm I have used several patterns, none is wrong I think. Matter of choice. For now I am passing interface for adapter callback and this way I can reuse adapter on few screens. I can extend interface in Fragment or ViewModel (so I can pass ViewModel too in constructor). I use that plus databinding and works great - for example I want to "like" post - Interface uses callback to tell Fragment about it, Fragment let's viewModel handle call and from call I am changing post model info (number of likes etc.) and it gets reflected using data binding in adapter

Answer (score 3):

Well, I looked for the solution for this question, but finally have to handle it myself. I would like to post my thought here for discussion.

Simply put, passing a viewModel instance to  adapter is not elegant, in my opinion. Instead, I recommend you **override the "onAttachedToRecyclerView" method of your RecyclerViewAdapter to get your viewModel**:

```
public class YoursAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
......
private YoursViewModel viewModel;
......
    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
        if(viewModel==null){
            viewModel=new ViewModelProvider((ViewModelStoreOwner) recyclerView.getContext()).get(YoursViewModel.class);
        }
    }
......
}
```

Why I think this solution is good?

1、ViewModel itself has nothing to do with contexts. But creating an instance of ViewModel needs a context.

2、Which context is your choice? The recyclerView's context, since you want to do something inside the adapter, and the adapter is associated with a recyclerView. Why I override the "onAttachedToRecyclerView"? Because this callback provides a recyclerView refference, and only executes once.

3、As long as the recyclerView's context is alive, the ViewModel is alive. Is it what you want? If the answer is "Yes", then it is reasonable to create your ViewModel instance based on the recyclerView's context.

4、You have had a ViewModel in Fragment. Is it reasonable to create a new one in adapter? Yes. [One of the advantages of ViewModel is sharing data](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#sharing), **as long as they are in the same activity**.

5、You actually don't need to observe a livedata inside an adapter (which needs context again), if you have properly designed the ViewModel. Basically you just observe a livedata on fragment. Your ViewModel inside an adapter is just responsible to change the data, not caring about how the data changed, i.e., do `yourViewModelInstance.post_value_to_liveData_and return_it().observe()` on fragment, and do `yourViewModelInstance.post_value_to_liveData_and return_it()` inside adapter.